# Starting nextcloud-snap

Tags: nextcloud

As per https://help.nextcloud.com/t/how-to-install-an-always-up-to-date-version-of-nextcloud-on-linux/596 I have succesfully run:

```
sudo snap install nextcloud
```

This downloads nextcloud and mounts it. I had expected that after doing this, I would be able to connect to http://localhost. But I get connection refused, so it seems there is a step in which I start the nextcloud service. I have, however, been unable to find that step.

What is the next step?

Answer (score 0):

In your link is answer:

> 1st login After a successful install, assuming you and the device on
>   which it was installed are on the same network, you should be able to
>   reach the Nextcloud installation by visiting **.local** in your browser.
>   If your hostname is localhost or localhost.localdomain, like on an
>   Ubuntu Core device (IoT), **nextcloud.local** will be used instead.

You must open .local or nextcloud.local in your browser.

Comment: Neither of those work.

Comment: do you have `/etc/apache2/sites-available/nextcloud.conf` file? what do you have in apache2 error logs? do you have any other webserver or apache virtual hosts?